# Can I reduce a dependent clause to present participle clause when its tense is simple past?

Tags: untagged

Can I reduce this

> 1 He dropped a brick, which caused his toe to break.

to this

> 1 He dropped a brick, causing his toe to break.

Comment: Yup. I don't know how to add more than that :)

Comment: You can reduce it still more to _breaking his toe_!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The tense of the main clause has no bearing on the matter.

Comment: True, but the whole point of non-finite clauses is to leave things inexplicit.  If I say "causing his toe to break", it isn't clear when the action took place. Only a subsequent finite clause resolves the issue, so in a way the main clause is relevant to the meaning.